# How can I change hierarchy database record to java object?

Tags: java, sql, hierarchical-data

I have hierarchy database record like following
(`0` means it doesn't have any parent)

```
parent_no   no
0           1
1           11
1           12
11          111
0           2
2           21
21          211
```

I'm currently developing one `api` using this table.
I have to make a result like following

```
[
  1 : [
    11 : [
      111 : []
    ]
    12 : []
  ]
  2 : [
    21 : [
      211 : []
    ]
  ]
]
```

Yeah, I just wanna convert above record to hierarchy object.
But... I don't know how to make it.
I guess I should make this query record to java object like

```
class SomeTable{
  Integer parentId;
  Integer id;
  List<SomeTable> list;
}
```

Although I gave a lot of thought, didn't figure out yet ...  T.T
Is there any good way to make it?

Comment: If your levels are fixed, then use left joins. Also think of using a recursive query.

Comment: Mention the database you are using.

Comment: We use `mysql` and our levels are not fixed. It can have infinite depth.

Comment: Also, be aware that this sort of structure is one of the most pathological in SQL and is often better suited for a different type of datastore. (See *friend-of-a-friend* query.)

Comment: You mean I can solve this when I use another database(like oracle) and use hierarchical query?